# PHP escrevendo javascript encriptado

Tags: php, javascript, lógica, criptografia

Estou com uma duvida em relação a um ofuscador de código javascript feito em php.. https://damidev.000webhostapp.com

alguém pode me ajudar a entender como esse cara fez pra encriptar? toda vez que é gerado o código ofuscado ele gera diferente do anterior mesmo o código sendo o mesmo

meu site esta sofrendo com crawlers, estão acessando o meu site e roubando informações pelo html.. com o método packer (packed) é fácil reconhecer um padrão e capturar oque quiser: [pastebin.com/BZEsmxNm](http://pastebin.com/BZEsmxNm).. porem com o método desse site [damidev.000webhostapp.com](http://damidev.000webhostapp.com) deixa tudo escondido: [pastebin.com/tw90KYSi](http://pastebin.com/tw90KYSi), assim dificultando a vida desses crawlers entendeu ? pois se você reparar ele sempre gera um código diferente mesmo com a mesma entrada de js .. tava estudando e percebi que é um método em XOR ou algo assim..

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente estes sistemas tem uma chave de encriptação que é usada de forma unica, justamente para não ter como desfazer e o objetivo é realmente fazer ele diferente a cada ciclo.

Dei uma olhada e ele muda as chaves a cada geração, não deve ser dificil de reproduzir isso em php caso você queira gerar sua própria rotina.

Comment: pois, eu só quero entender que método ele usa pra encriptar, tentei estudar o código porem não consigo entender muito bem e fazer a engenharia reversa ..